# PowerShell ConvertFrom-SecureString in Java?

Tags: java, powershell, encryption

I'm trying to re-implement [PowerShell's ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-6) in Java. The documentation there is a bit sparse. All it says is "AES". Trying out various AES encryption examples on the Java side did not get me any further.

Would someone have some pointers for me?

---

Addendum 1

The pointers provided by the comments look helpful. Thanks!

This PowerShell script shows what I'm trying to "port" to Java, at least the encryption part (with key being just 32 random byte values):

```
$key = 202,144,73,88,228,1,7,104,95,212,137,87,125,201,80,75,53,18,39,108,60,218,212,151,239,241,34,117,106,184,212,179

$secret = "banana"
Write-Output "secret   : $($secret)"

# encrypt
$secretSecured = ConvertTo-SecureString $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$encrypted = ConvertFrom-SecureString -secureString $secretSecured -key $key
Write-Output "encrypted: $($encrypted)"

# decrypt
$secure = $encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
$decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
Write-Output "decrypted: $($decrypted)"
```

Running it gives this:

```
secret   : banana
encrypted: 76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AEkAdQBpAEIANQBaAHQAeQAvAE0AOQBpAE0ATwByAEEAcgBlAC8AOQB2AGcAPQA9AHwANwBkAGIANwBiADgAYgBhADIAZgA4ADAAZQBlADEAZQA0ADgAYQA1ADUAYgBiADYAZgAyADQAMQA5ADkAMwA5AA==
decrypted: banana
```

---

Addendum 2

Here's now a first draft port in Java (also [in this Github repository](https://github.com/m2spring/powershell-convertfrom-securestring-in-java)):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;

public class EncryptionTest{

    SecretKeySpec key;
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    Cipher cipher;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception{
        int[] ints = {202,144,73,88,228,1,7,104,95,212,137,87,125,201,80,75,53,18,39,108,60,218,212,151,239,241,34,117,106,184,212,179};
        byte[] bytes = new byte[ints.length];
        for (int i=0; i<ints.length; i++){
            bytes[i] = (byte)ints[i];
        }
        key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES");

        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    }

    @Test
    public void testIt() throws Exception{
        String secret = "banana";

        System.out.println("secret   : "+secret);

        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(secret);
        System.out.println("encrypted: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted));

        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
        System.out.println("decrypted: "+decrypted);
    }

    byte[] encrypt(String secret) throws Exception{
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(secret.getBytes());
    }

    String decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws Exception{
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    }
}
```

Running it (in JUnit) gives this:

```
secret   : banana
encrypted: P51DH0d0FRvUoetaujEyjA==
decrypted: banana
```

I wonder why the encrypted string here is only 24 characters long, but the PowerShell one has 192 characters?

Comment: SecureString uses DPAPI, see if a [Java wrapper](https://github.com/peter-gergely-horvath/windpapi4j) works.

Comment: [Check out](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bd6fdae73520931f0d27a29d6290e18761772141/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/security/SecureStringCommands.cs) [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bd6fdae73520931f0d27a29d6290e18761772141/src/System.Management.Automation/security/SecureStringHelper.cs) - particularly [the platform calls](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bd6fdae73520931f0d27a29d6290e18761772141/src/System.Management.Automation/security/SecureStringHelper.cs#L617-L637) you'll need to marshal